# How to reset value stored in local storage by Get Storage after a set time interval for example 1 day?

Tags: flutter, datetime, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

```
`var toBeResetValue = 3.4;
var storage = GetStorage();
storage.write("value", toBeResetValue);`
```

//After 24 hours or set interval the value stored goes to 0 instead of 3.4. How to proceed forward?

//`//Code in Flutter 3.7.12 using GetX state management`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the legacy code has been there with getX and Get storage .. let me know if there is any fix to this